# Is there a trick to pressing the "u" button in the Surface Pro 2 on-screen keyboard?

Tags: microsoft-surface, on-screen-keyboard

I find it exceedingly difficult to hit the <kbd>U</kbd> on the on-screen keyboard on my Surface Pro 2 running Windows 8.1.  Here are the specific symptoms:

- very carefully tapping directly over the on-screen <kbd>U</kbd> usually results in a "y" character
- compensating by tapping slightly further to the right on the screen usually result in an "i" character
- starting over the <kbd>Y</kbd> and successively tapping my way over to the <kbd>P</kbd> a constant 1/4 of a key width at a a time yields this string: "yyyyyyyyiiiooooppppp" -- note that <kbd>u</kbd> was not pressed once and <kbd>Y</kbd> is much wider than the others.

Things I've tried with no noticeable difference:

- calibrating both pen and touch
- turning tablet 180 degrees

Is there something I can do to make my on-screen <kbd>U</kbd> usable?

Comment: Yes.  (See my second to last bullet.)

Answer (score 0):

### Update the Wacom Enhanced Tablet Driver

Upgrading to the [Wacom-distributed driver for Surface Pro 2](http://us.wacom.com/en/feeldriver/) "Enhanced Tablet Driver 7.2.1-24" seems to have fixed this problem.  That drivers seems to work better than whatever driver was coming through the automatic Windows Updates.